# how to fill na with a specific value based on a condition

Tags: date, fillna

Still learning python, and struggling with dates and na's.. I have a situation as the image below would show
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2x0i8.png)

for the NAT values in the column EndDT_New, i would like to fill them with a specific value based on a condition, eg:

if the DATE_ACT_CLOSED = '01/01/2040' then replace just the NAT in EndDT_New with 30/03/2021 else
if the DATE_ACT_CLOSED <> '01/01/2040', then replace just the NAT in EndDT_New with the value in DATE_ACT_CLOSED .

My previous experience is in SAS, so its quite a learning curve and mind shift to python.

Any help is much appreciated.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 0):

i reckon i figured it out.

df_all_valid.loc[(np.isnat(df_all_valid['EndDT_New'])==True) & (df_all_valid['DATE_ACT_CLOSED'] == '01/01/2040'), 'EndDT_New'] = np.datetime64('2021-03-30')